# MYSQL - UPDATE but keep old information

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I've read tons of questions who are in many ways the same as this one. But I just can't seem to understand how I am supposed to do this the proper way.

- I've got one table with my pages.
- And one table with portfolio items.
- I want to be able to say to a portfolio item: You are linked to the welcome page now.

**My approach:**

- In my pages table i've created a "items_linked" column. Inside this column the id's of the linked portfolio items get stored.
- In the html of the 'edit page' I have a select with all my portfolio items, whichever I select gets stored inside the "items_linked".
- I use the mysql UPDATE to get the information inside the database.

However this way I can't link a portfolio item to more than 1 page. 
Because UPDATE removes the old information.
So I was guessing I needed a way to keep the old info, and add new info if the item is linked to a second page. 
Can someone push me into the right direction?

Comment: hello, and welcome to SO. it seems your question is a little off-topic, since this site is about specific coding problems, while your question seems to be about basic understanding. but to answer your question: add a relationship-table with two columns, one pointing to your pages, the other to your items. in there, you can add as many relations as you want. (called n-m-relationship)

Comment: Thanks for you reply; I was googling at so many things, but now I know this is called 'n-m-relationship' I'm sure im gonna learn it tonight :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we have no way of knowing what we are replacing I can only give you an idea of what to do:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `myColumn` = CONCAT(`myColumn`, other_data)
WHERE some_condition_exists
```

This causes the information in `myColumn` to have [additional data appended to it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

Here's the thing (*caveat ahead*): If you need one item to be linked to many items what I have described *is not the way to go*. You should have a table between the two you have already which will allow a one-to-many relationship between pages and portfolios. Please consider refactoring your database design.

Comment: Thanks for you reply; I was googling at so many things, but now I know I know that a relationship approach is the way to go :) Thnx!